# Por que só um Encoding funciona no algoritmo?

Tags: c#, .net, string, codificação-de-caracteres

É o seguinte: tenho um módulo de criptografia que encripta um `byte[]` e saí outro `byte[]` encriptado, e no final da saída é colocado um checksum; o checksum é um único byte gerado pelo aplicativo feito pela chave assimétrica, assim pode verificar se a decriptografia bate com as chaves, de entrada e de saída.

O problema, é que se eu fazer `byte[] -> byte[]` funciona perfeitamente, encriptando e decriptando. Mas se eu converter esses `byte[]` para Strings, só funcionam se eu usar um Encoding, e dá erro de **checksum inválido** se eu usar outro encoding.

```
string TextoParaEncriptar = "Olá, mundo!";
string encriptado = cipher.EncryptString(TextoBytes); // ok, encripta normalmente
string decriptado = cipher.DecryptString(encriptado); // beleza também
```

Acima o código dá certo, o campo `decriptado` tem como valor "Olá, mundo!", mas ambos métodos usaram o encoder `Encoding.Default`, que é variável de acordo com a máquina em execução. Agora se eu especificar o encoder, dá erro:

```
string TextoParaEncriptar = "Olá, mundo!";
string encriptado = cipher.EncryptString(TextoBytes, Encoding.ASCII); // ok, encripta normalmente
string decriptado = cipher.DecryptString(encriptado, Encoding.ASCII); // checksum inválido
```

Estes são o código dos métodos para encriptar/descriptar strings:

```
    public string EncryptString(string inputString) => EncryptString(inputString, Encoding.Default);
    public string EncryptString(string inputString, Encoding byteEncoder)
    {
        byte[] strBytes = byteEncoder.GetBytes(inputString);
        EncryptByteArray(ref strBytes);
        return byteEncoder.GetString(strBytes);
    }
    public string DecryptString(string inputString) => DecryptString(inputString, Encoding.Default);
    public string DecryptString(string inputString, Encoding byteEncoder)
    {
        byte[] strBytes = byteEncoder.GetBytes(inputString);
        DecryptByteArray(ref strBytes);
        return byteEncoder.GetString(strBytes);
    }
```

Códigos para encriptar e descriptografar:

```
    public void EncryptByteArray(ref byte[] inputData)
    {
        if (k == null || k.Length == 0) throw new NullReferenceException("Key cannot be emtpy.");
        if (inputData == null || inputData.Length == 0) return;
        CryrazCore processor = new CryrazCore() { Positions = k };
        {
            processor.ComputeByteArray(ref inputData, false);
            Array.Resize(ref inputData, inputData.Length + 1);
            byte checksum = processor.PushChecksun();
            {
                inputData[inputData.Length - 1] = checksum;
            }
        }
    }
    public void DecryptByteArray(ref byte[] inputData)
    {
        if (k == null || k.Length == 0) throw new NullReferenceException("Key cannot be emtpy.");
        if (inputData == null || inputData.Length == 0) return;
        CryrazCore processor = new CryrazCore() { Positions = k };
        byte dataChecksum = inputData[inputData.Length - 1];
        byte processorChecksum = processor.PushChecksun();
        if(dataChecksum != processorChecksum) throw new NullReferenceException("Invalid key for this data. Checksum check failed.");
        {
            inputData[inputData.Length - 1] = 0;
            Array.Resize(ref inputData, inputData.Length - 1);
            processor.ComputeByteArray(ref inputData, true);
        }
    }
```

> - **`processor.ComputeByteArray(ref byte[], boolean)`**: É o método que processa *byte-por-byte* do `byte[]` recebido.
> - **`EncryptByteArray`** insere o `byte` checksum no final da cadeia, o método **`DecryptByteArray`** remove-o antes de de processar a descriptografia.

Por que está dando erro, mesmo usando o mesmo `Encoding` para encriptar e descriptar apenas quando o `Encoding byteEncoder` não é `Encoding.Default`? Como resolvo isto?

## Atualização

Se eu usar o Encoding *Western European (ISO) ISO-8859*, cujo é *SBCS (Single Byte Character Set)*, que é um byte para cada caractere, o algoritmo funciona normalmente. Mas ainda não entendo.

O algoritmo percorre todos os bytes recebidos pelo `GetBytes()` e coloca um checksum no final dessa cadeia de bytes, e depois converte-os para uma String usando um `GetString(byte[])` pelo que veio encriptado, após descriptar essa mesma cadeia encriptada, diz que o último byte foi alterado.

Comment: Pode fornecer os algoritmos de encriptacao e desencriptacao?

Comment: @BrunoCosta atualizei a pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função de um *character encoding* é codificar um certo "texto" para bytes e de volta para texto. Para um *encoding* ser completo, toda sequência possível de textos deve ter uma representação em bytes (um *encoding* incompleto somente suporta um subconjunto dos caracteres possíveis - como por exemplo o ASCII). No entanto, nem toda sequência possível de bytes precisa corresponder a um texto válido em qualquer *encoding*. Se você usar uma sequência arbitrária de bytes e tentar converter para texto, é possível que não saia nada coerente daí.

Por isso, se você tenta representar a sequência de bytes criptografada (que é indistinguível de uma sequência de bytes aleatórios) em um *encoding* qualquer há grande chance desses bytes não representarem nenhum texto válido. Sobretudo no UTF-8, que tem regras bem rígidas quanto ao que os primeiros bits representam.

Sendo assim, eu sugiro usar outro tipo de representação para sua string criptografada - digamos base 64 ou talvez hex. Exemplo:

```
public string EncryptString(string inputString) => EncryptString(inputString, GetCryrazStringEncoder());
internal string EncryptString(string inputString, Encoding byteEncoder)
{
    byte[] strBytes = byteEncoder.GetBytes(inputString); // Texto usa encoding
    EncryptByteArray(ref strBytes);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(strBytes); // Bytes aleatórios usam base64
}

public string DecryptString(string inputString) => DecryptString(inputString, GetCryrazStringEncoder());
internal string DecryptString(string inputString, Encoding byteEncoder)
{
    byte[] strBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString); // Bytes aleatórios usam base64
    DecryptByteArray(ref strBytes);
    return byteEncoder.GetString(strBytes); // Texto usa encoding
}
```

Comment: Fantástico! Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 2):

Sendo bem superficial: ASCII não suporta acentuação.

Se espera receber acentuação - ou textos com caracteres binários - utilize `Encoding.UTF8`.

Veja como eles se comportam, em conversões simples.

```
var original = "Olá, Hello World";
Console.WriteLine("Original: " + original);

var ascBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(original);
var backFromASCII = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ascBytes);
Console.WriteLine("ASCII: " + backFromASCII);

var utfBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(original);
var backFromUTF8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utfBytes);
Console.WriteLine("UTF8: " + backFromUTF8);

var iso8859 = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var isoBytes = iso8859.GetBytes(original);
var backFromISO = iso8859.GetString(isoBytes);
Console.WriteLine("ISO-8859: " + backFromISO);
```

A saída sera:

```
// Original: Olá, Hello World
// ASCII: Ol?, Hello World
// UTF8: Olá, Hello World
// ISO-8859: Olá, Hello World
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pSECxz).

Comment: Os bytes são alterados com a codificação? Porque tentei fazer com UTF-8 para UTF-8 e também dá erro no Checksum, diz que é inválido o mesmo.

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta com algumas pistas para encontrar o problema.

Comment: Mas o problema está no ASCII. Foi isso que eu mostrei na resposta. Veja que com ISO-8859-1 também é possivel fazer proval real da conversão .

Comment: Estranho que se eu usar o UTF-8 também dá erro.

Comment: Joga no net fiddle e posta aqui que dou uma olhada.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o .NETF.